# How to draw this kind of 3D axes with Plotly in Python?

Tags: python, plotly

Plotly is an excellent data visualization solution. But I don't like the default style of 3D axes. I want to know, how to draw this kind of 3D axes with Plotly in Python?

[image]

Comment: Is that image also created with Plotly?

Comment: Documentation does not help - D Line Plots in Python - https://plot.ly/python/3d-line-plots/?

Comment: Any updates on this?